# list Comprehension - comparing one list to another list with indexing

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list that comprises a list of tweets:

`twitter_dataset_list = [['322185112684994561', '@Bill_Porter nice to know that your site is back :-)'], ['322185112684994545', 'I had a bad day']]`

I want to compare each of those elements' messages to see if they are positive or negative with the following list

`positive_keyword_list = ['nice']`

`negative_keyword_list = ['bad']`

if they are positive / negative then I want to append a flag to each of the initial list, like this:

`[['322185112684994561', '@Bill_Porter nice to know that your site is back :-)', 1], ['322185112684994545', 'I had a bad day', -1]]`

Ive done this, but I'm not sure how to iterate and sub-index

```
for element in twitter_dataset_list:
    if any(word in twitter_dataset_list[0][1] for word in positive_keyword_list) == True:
        twitter_dataset_list.append('1')
    elif any(word in twitter_dataset_list[0][1] for word in negative_keyword_list) == True:
        twitter_dataset_list.append('-1')
    else:
        twitter_dataset_list[0][1].append('0')

print(twitter_dataset_list)

So how do I iterate over the twitter_dataset_list
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function is useful here, because it'll give you both the index and the values as you iterate over the list.

Second, you can unpack as you go using the `for i, (id, text) in` syntax.

And finally, you can use `_` for any unpacking that you don't actually use in the loop. (Here, I don't need the ID, so I just put `_` to tell python not to worry about it.)

More details on the different ways you can unpack things in loops is available from the [Python docs' on data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

```py
for i, (_, text) in enumerate(twitter_dataset_list):
    if any(word in text for word in positive_keyword_list):
        twitter_dataset_list[i].append(1)
    elif any(word in text for word in negative_keyword_list):
        twitter_dataset_list[i].append(-1)
    else:
        twitter_dataset_list[i].append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not altering the original data, and instead returning a new list:

```py
positive_keyword_set = {"nice",}
negative_keyword_set = {"bad",}

tweets_with_sentiments = []
for tweet_id, tweet in twitter_dataset_list:
    sentiment = 0
    words = tweet.lower().split()
    if negative_keyword_set.intersection(words):
        sentiment = -1
    elif positive_keyword_set.intersection(words):
        sentiment = 1
    tweets_with_sentiments.append([tweet_id, tweet, sentiment])
```

Note that I've also converted your keyword lists to `set`. This allows for `O(1)` lookups since the values stored in the `set` can be hashed. It also allows you to simply use `set.intersection()` on the tweet's words to find the keywords:

```py
>>> tweet = '@Bill_Porter nice to know that your site is back :-)'

>>> tweet.lower().split()
['@bill_porter',
 'nice',
 'to',
 'know',
 'that',
 'your',
 'site',
 'is',
 'back',
 ':-)']

>>> positive_keyword_set.intersection(tweet.split())
{'nice'}
```

In fact, I'd suggest going so far as using a `dict` to store tweet sentiment:

```py
positive_keyword_set = {"nice",}
negative_keyword_set = {"bad",}

tweets_with_sentiments = {}
for tweet_id, tweet in twitter_dataset_list:
    sentiment = 0
    if negative_keyword_set.intersection(tweet.split()):
        sentiment = -1
    elif positive_keyword_set.intersection(tweet.split()):
        sentiment = 1
    tweets_with_sentiments[int(tweet_id)] = dict(tweet=tweet, sentiment=sentiment)
```

Now your data structure can be accessed in `O(1)` by the tweet ID:

```py
>>> tweets_with_sentiments
{322185112684994561: {'tweet': '@Bill_Porter nice to know that your site is back :-)', 'sentiment': 1},
 322185112684994545: {'tweet': 'I had a bad day', 'sentiment': -1}}

>>> tweets_with_sentiments[322185112684994561]["sentiment"]
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function to handle the sentiment, as I assume this part of code may evolve (I use [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/) lib for a similar app):

```
twitter_dataset_list = [['322185112684994561', '@Bill_Porter nice to know that your site is back :-)'],
                        ['322185112684994545', 'I had a bad day']]

def tweet_sentiment(tweet_text:str)->list:
    # https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python#:~:text=Use%20any()%20to%20check,to%20build%20the%20generator%20expression.
    positive_keyword_list = ['nice']
    negative_keyword_list = ['bad']
    if any(' '+keyword.lower()+' ' in tweet_text.lower() for keyword in positive_keyword_list):
        return [1]
    if any(' '+keyword.lower()+' ' in tweet_text.lower()  for keyword in negative_keyword_list):
        return [-1]
    return [0]

twitter_dataset_list = [tweet_details + tweet_sentiment(tweet_text=tweet_details[1]) for tweet_details in twitter_dataset_list]
print(twitter_dataset_list)
```

Answer edited to take account of Kumar's comment regarding partial match. As well, using lower() to match either upper or lower case matches